# Выпадает exception при повторном использовании BufferedReader. Exception: Stream closed. Почему и как правильно это использовать?

Tags: java, исключения, потоки-данных, io

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // =========
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Зачем повторное использование? Почему не использовать первый?

Comment: Это упрощенный пример, чтобы не вставлять весь код. Вообще используются несколько различных методов в разных классах и возникла данная проблема.

Comment: `Почему?` – потому что при закрытии `BufferedReader` автоматически закрываются все вложенные потоки.

Comment: А можно подробнее? Как правильно тогда использовать в структуре с несколькими классами?

Comment: А вы обьект ридера, что, передаете по всем функциям?

Answer (score 1):

Исключение `IOException` генерируется потому, что после первого использования `BufferedReader reader` Вы его сразу неявно (с помощью `try-with-resources`) закрываете.

Закрытие `BufferedReader reader` ведет к автоматическому закрытию всех вложенных в него потоков, в частности и `System.in`. Поток `System.in` *переоткрыть* невозможно, поэтому при последующем использовании `System.in` Вы и получаете сообщение, что `Stream closed`.

Если Вам нужно использовать поток ввода в различных классах, то, например, можете сделать инстанс `BufferedReader` публичным статическим полем `Main`-класса:

```
public static BufferedReader sReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

и использовать его как:

```
String s = Main.sReader.readLine();
```

Но в таком случае, после последнего ввода, не забудьте его закрыть:

```
Main.sReader.close();
```