# Закрытие потока ввода в Java

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Метод:

```
public void find() {
    String input = null;
    BufferedReader bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        input = bRead.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(bRead != null) {
            try {
                bRead.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Возникают ошибки:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfOpen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:336)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
```

main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();
    b.find();
    b.find();
}
```

Поток ввода должен закрываться в секции `finally`. Как сделать это, чтобы ничего не падало?

Comment: Приведите весь код. Здесь не должно возникнуть ошибок!

Comment: @Victor, это весь код. Они возникают

Comment: в каком месте падает вы знаете?

Comment: Ошибка происходит потому, что вы закрываете поток `bRead.close();` и потом второй раз его вызываете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Закрывая BufferedReader вы закрываете все вложенные в него потоки.**
Вот вам похожий пример [Выпадает exception при повторном использовании BufferedReader. Exception: Stream closed. Почему и как правильно это использовать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/598288/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-exception-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-bufferedreader-exception-stream)

Удалите в методе `find()` блок finally. И добавьте метод `close()` вот так:

```
public class B {

private BufferedReader bRead;

public B(){
    bRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}

public void find() {
    String input = null;
    try {
        input = bRead.readLine();
        System.out.println(input);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void close() {
    try {
        bRead.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Main:

```
public class JavaStackOverflow {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.find();
    b.find();
    b.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ошибок нет!Возможно не выполнены все условия?

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/G3VH/7.js"></script>
```

Закрывая `bRead` вы тем самым закрываете все вложенные потоки.
и при попытке повторного чтения `System.in` закрыт. Поэтому вынесите закрытие потока в отдельный метод и вызывайте только тогда когда работа с вводом.выводом завершена!

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  B b = new B();
  try{
    b.find();
    b.find();
  } finally{
    CloseReader();
  }
}
```